# Modifying an existing Jekyll theme to have static homepage

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, static-site, jekyll-theme

I'm making a site using this theme: [Github repo](https://github.com/Sylhare/Type-on-Strap); [theme demo](https://sylhare.github.io/Type-on-Strap/).

The theme is built with the blog feed on the homepage (`index.html`). What I would like to do instead is:

1. make a static homepage (i.e. no blog feed on the homepage), *and*
2. have the blog feed live on a separate page called "Blog", with the link "/blog" or "/blog.html".

The code for the blog feed lives in `_includes/blog.html` and is included in the `home` layout using `{% include blog.html %}`.

**What I've tried**

- changed the layout of `index.html` to a static layout like `page`, and created a new page in the root called `blog.html` with the layout `home` - this succeeded in creating a static homepage, but the blog page yields a home-like header but no blog feed (essentially a page with no content).
- created a new page in the root called `blog.html` with the layout `default`, and pasted the content of the home layout (including `{% include blog.html %}`) into that page - this yielded the same result as above.
- created a new layout called `blog`, which is a copy of the current `home` layout. I deleted the line `{% include blog.html %}` from the `home` layout. Then I gave `index.html` the `home` layout and created a new page in the root called `blog.html` with the layout `blog`. This yielded the same result as above.

In short, it seems like the blog feed isn't able to generate in any file other than `index.html`, and I haven't been able to figure out why. Is it something I'm missing in the theme's configuration? Apologies if this turns out to be a dumb question - I'm rather new to this. Thank you for any help you can give me!

EDIT: Turns out it was an issue with the paginator, which by default paginates from home.

Comment: How you solved your paginator issue though ?

Comment: @iatharva, the pagination logic only works in `index.html` files. If you want to generate the blog feed with paginator on a non-home page, like I did, you should make another directory in the root and create a new `index.html` file in that directory. Ex.: I created a `blog` directory in the root and created `index.html` inside that, where I put all my pagination/blog feed code. That generates a blog feed at baseurl/blog

Comment: I have already added ```blog.html``` in ```_includes``` folder but still not working. Can you elaborate what do you mean by creating a directory in the root?

Comment: can you explain it in detail? or just add answer to this post by telling how you solved it @olvoku

Answer (score 1):

The index.html uses the home layout:

```
---
layout: home
---
```

This lives in `_layouts/home.html` and contains a header and includes blog.html. It looks like this:

```
---
layout: default
---

<div class="home">

    <div id="main" class="call-out"
         style="background-image: url('{{ site.header_feature_image | relative_url }}')">
        <h1> {{ site.header_text | default: "Change <code>header_text</code> in <code>_config.yml</code>"}} </h1>
    </div>

    {% include blog.html %}

</div>
```

The blog.html file loops over all (blog) posts:

```
<div class="posts">
    {% for post in paginator.posts %}
...
```

To solve your issue, you need to define your own home page as an include like this:

1. Create `your-custom-homepage.html` with html of your choice.
2. Include it in `home.html` as `{% include your-custom-homepage.html %}` instead of `{% include blog.html %}`. Just replace the line in `_layouts/home.html`.

Then it will contain the header and your content.

The Jekyll documentation, e.g. https://jekyllrb.com/docs/step-by-step/04-layouts/ and https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/ will hopefully explain the details.